# How do i view what changes have been commited but pending push in SourceTree

Tags: git, sourcetree

I am not a developer and i have recently started getting my hands on Sourcetree and git.
I see that i have 7 changes committed in the master and pending push.
I no longer want to push these changes. But i want to view what these '7 changes' were?. how can i do that?
Also, please advise if in order to undo the commit , i should just do 'reverse commit' on the highlighted row.

thank you!
[image: Sourcetree snagit]

Comment: If you want to _see_ what you did in a commit, just select it (as you have it) and look at the bottom right of SourceTree's window; it shows you everything. If you want to _undo_ what you did in the most recent commit, just hard reset back to the previous commit.

Comment: thanks @matt , but it just shows me the latest code i pushed in the bottom right, i dont know what the 6 other pending code pushes stand for?.

Comment: Select all 7 of them simultaneously. Now the bottom shows the content of all 7 commits.

Comment: ah thanks :) i didnt know blue line on the left stands for the changes to the code at different point in time.

Comment: SourceTree is really quite excellent, but you're really not going to be comfortable using it unless you learn some git. You apparently don't know what a commit _is_; you'll be a lot happier when you do. :)

Comment: @matt Then why Visual studio 2019 Team Explorer, for example, provides this feature? At the Synchroniztion tab you can see a list of outgoing and incoming commits, and see all file differences within every commit. So why Sourcetree can't do the same?

Answer (score -2):

You can see the files in a commit even in any status (pushed or not) on the history tab. Select the commit in question and look in the window below on the left side.

[image: Files in commit]

Answer (score -4):

To reverse a commit using source tree just right click on the desired commit message and click reverse commit.

Comment: Does not answer "what commit(s)" are pending a push. Finding the "desired" commit(s) is the question.